# How can I use StateListAnimator in my application

Tags: android, animation, state

I want to make animation for buttons in my application.
Recently heard about StateListAnimator
Tell me more about  StateListAnimator
How can I use it in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StateListAnimator to provide animations when the state of your view changes. From:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

> The StateListAnimator class lets you define animators that run when the state of a view changes. The following example shows how to define an StateListAnimator as an XML resource:

```
<!-- animate the translationZ property of a view when pressed -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:valueTo="2dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <!-- you could have other objectAnimator elements
              here for "x" and "y", or other properties -->
    </set>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:duration="100"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
  </item>
</selector>
```

> To attach custom view state animations to a view, define an animator using the selector element in an XML resource file as in this example, and assign it to your view with the android:stateListAnimator attribute. To assign a state list animator to a view in your code, use the AnimationInflater.loadStateListAnimator() method, and assign the animator to your view with the View.setStateListAnimator() method.
>
> When your theme extends the material theme, buttons have a Z animation by default. To avoid this behavior in your buttons, set the android:stateListAnimator attribute to @null.
>
> The AnimatedStateListDrawable class lets you create drawables that show animations between state changes of the associated view. Some of the system widgets in Android 5.0 use these animations by default. The following example shows how to define an AnimatedStateListDrawable as an XML resource:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myanimstatedrawable.xml -->
<animated-selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
<item android:id="@+id/pressed" android:drawable="@drawable/drawableP"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:id="@+id/focused" android:drawable="@drawable/drawableF"
    android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:id="@id/default"
    android:drawable="@drawable/drawableD"/>

<!-- specify a transition -->
<transition android:fromId="@+id/default" android:toId="@+id/pressed">
    <animation-list>
        <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/dt1"/>
        <item android:duration="15" android:drawable="@drawable/dt2"/>
        ...
    </animation-list>
</transition>
...
</animated-selector>
```

Comment: How can I create xml-file? where ?

Comment: You want to add an xml file to the res folder in your project.

Comment: so i created xml-file animation.xml in res folder                                                             what's next ?

Comment: I would look through the android tutorials on animation. There are plenty of examples from which you can learn from.

Comment: I found very few materials about it                                                           Can you suggest something ?

Comment: The correct class is actually AnimatorInflator, not AnimationInflator, fyi!